# Resource request: labelling irreducible representations of $U(n)$ by standard Young tableaux

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am going through *Group Theory: Birdtracks, Lie's, and Exceptional Groups* by Predrag Cvitanović.

It is stated that the irreducible representations of $U(n)$ can be labelled by the standard Young tableaux with no more than $n$ rows.

Are there any good resources to understand how this is done?

Comment: Cool with [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau)? Most quark model introductions have a Young tableaux refresher.

Comment: [These notes](http://www.astro.sunysb.edu/steinkirch/books/group.pdf) are useful for this.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The irreducible representations are labelled by partitions with at most $n$ rows, once you’ve chosen a partition then there is a basis of that representation labelled by semistandard young tableaux of that shape. I like the book *Young Tableaux* by Fulton, but perhaps that is a little too mathematical-leaning rather than physics-leaning depending on your background.